# Create Pandas DataFrame with new dates index and new columns with substring of headers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to transform the DataFrame df below into another one:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'dates':['01/01/2018','02/01/2018','03/01/2018','04/01/2018','05/01/2018'],
    'A X':[1,1,2,1,1],
    'A Y':[1,1,3,1,1],
    'A Z':[1,1,4,1,1],
    'B X':[2,2,3,2,2],
    'B Y':[2,2,4,2,2],
    'C X':[3,3,4,3,3]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['dates','A X','A Y','A Z','B X','B Y','C X'])
```

Desired DataFrame:

```
dates   fields  A   B   C
01/01/2018  X   1   2   3
02/01/2018  X   1   2   3
03/01/2018  X   2   3   4
04/01/2018  X   1   2   3
05/01/2018  X   1   2   3
01/01/2018  Y   1   2   nan
02/01/2018  Y   1   2   nan
03/01/2018  Y   3   4   nan
04/01/2018  Y   1   2   nan
05/01/2018  Y   1   2   nan
01/01/2018  Z   1   nan nan
02/01/2018  Z   1   nan nan
03/01/2018  Z   4   nan nan
04/01/2018  Z   1   nan nan
05/01/2018  Z   1   nan nan
```

Dates were set as the new index values, a new column called 'fields' was inserted which holds the string 'X', 'Y', 'Z' extracted from df's column headers. How can I accomplish this?
(pandas v0.22)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

- [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for columns only with space
- [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) columns for `MultiIndex`
- reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
- [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for columns from `index`
- `rename` column
- sort DataFrame by column `fields` by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

---

```
df = df.set_index('dates')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(expand=True)
df = df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'fields'}).sort_values('fields')
print (df)

         dates fields  A    B    C
0   01/01/2018      X  1  2.0  3.0
3   02/01/2018      X  1  2.0  3.0
6   03/01/2018      X  2  3.0  4.0
9   04/01/2018      X  1  2.0  3.0
12  05/01/2018      X  1  2.0  3.0
1   01/01/2018      Y  1  2.0  NaN
4   02/01/2018      Y  1  2.0  NaN
7   03/01/2018      Y  3  4.0  NaN
10  04/01/2018      Y  1  2.0  NaN
13  05/01/2018      Y  1  2.0  NaN
2   01/01/2018      Z  1  NaN  NaN
5   02/01/2018      Z  1  NaN  NaN
8   03/01/2018      Z  4  NaN  NaN
11  04/01/2018      Z  1  NaN  NaN
14  05/01/2018      Z  1  NaN  NaN
```

---

Thank you  @Paul H for improvin answer:

```
df = (df.set_index('dates')
       .rename(columns=lambda c: tuple(c.split()))
       .stack()
       .rename_axis(('dates','fields'))
       .sort_index(level='fields')
       .reset_index()
       )
print (df)


         dates fields  A    B    C
0   01/01/2018      X  1  2.0  3.0
1   02/01/2018      X  1  2.0  3.0
2   03/01/2018      X  2  3.0  4.0
3   04/01/2018      X  1  2.0  3.0
4   05/01/2018      X  1  2.0  3.0
5   01/01/2018      Y  1  2.0  NaN
6   02/01/2018      Y  1  2.0  NaN
7   03/01/2018      Y  3  4.0  NaN
8   04/01/2018      Y  1  2.0  NaN
9   05/01/2018      Y  1  2.0  NaN
10  01/01/2018      Z  1  NaN  NaN
11  02/01/2018      Z  1  NaN  NaN
12  03/01/2018      Z  4  NaN  NaN
13  04/01/2018      Z  1  NaN  NaN
14  05/01/2018      Z  1  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: fun fact: you can now do `df = df.rename(columns=lambda c: tuple(c.split()))` and it'll expand for you, so you can add that to the front of your chain

Comment: you can also use `rename_axis` to avoid `.rename(columns={'level_1':'fields'})`, which I never like doing b/c who knows if it's gonna be `level_0` or `level_1` or `level_N` in a big long chain

Comment: @robertoswiss - Glad can help you.